# How to add 2 different flags for button clicks so that can add extra stuff to html view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having 2 button fields which are redirected to same html page,

```
  = link_to url_for(params.merge(action: 'my_report', format: :html)), class: 'button on-dark right', data: { toggle: 'modal',  placement: 'left' } do
    = t('reports.pdf_export')
  = link_to url_for(params.merge(action: 'show', format: :pdf)), class: 'button on-dark right' do
    = t('reports.all_pdf_export')
```

In that html I want to add extra stuff when we click on **all_pdf_export** button, can we add this by name or any flag to be added?
Please help me.

controller method:

```
  def customer_report
    @x = params[:x]
    @y = params[:y]
    @details = Detail.by_account(current_account).active.includes(:company, :primary_contact)
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html{ render layout: "modal" }
    end
  end
```

Button view:

```
= link_to url_for(params.merge(action: 'my_report', format: :html)), class: 'button on-dark right', data: { toggle: 'modal',  placement: 'left' } do
   = t('reports.pdf_export') 
= button_to t('reports.all_pdf_export'), url_for(params.merge(action: 'customer_report', format: :html)), class: 'button on-dark right', params: { x: "value", y: "value" }, data: { toggle: 'modal',  placement: 'left' } do
```

common view for both the links:

```
<div>
 <%= @account.name %> <br/>
 <%= @account.description %><br/>
<% if @x? %>
 <%= @account.details %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to add label(name) on each link?

Comment: Not label name, for example in my html page i am printing name field which is common for that 2 links and when I click on "all_pdf_export", I want to add description field. For this we need some if condition with flag or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be best using [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), which creates a small form, allowing you the luxury of passing `params` through it:

```
= button_to t('reports.all_pdf_export'), url_for(params.merge(action: 'show', format: :pdf)), class: 'button on-dark right', params: { x: "value", y: "value" }
```

> (`button_to`) generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options. This is the safest method to ensure links that cause changes to your data are not triggered by search bots or accelerators.

If using the above, you'll be able to access the parameters in your controller as follows:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @x = params[:x]
    @y = params[:y]
  end
end
```

---

**Update**

You must remember to evaluate *against* the `variable` you set:

```
<%= @account.name %> <br/>
<%= @account.description %><br/>
<%= @account.details if @x == "value" %>
```

Comment: WHen I give `<% if @x %> <% cust.name %> <% end %>`, It is not displaying in both the conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by "both conditions"? Can you post your updated code?

Comment: I put the same  params in button click and I added 2 values in my controller. in my view file there are different fields like `<% cust.name %> <%cust.description %> <% cust.address %>`. Now I have to write a condition, where when I click on this button the name field has to be shown or else not.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. I need to see your code that you have now, so that I can point out what to do